# android Textview make Drawable clickable?

Tags: android, listview, drawable

i have new's feed `ListView` and each item content text and images , the images has been drawled by `ImageGetter()` from remote server

so my question is what is the simplest way to make those images clickable ? like if user want to view picture in large mode , aim still newer for android `drawable` where to start ?

Answer (score 0):

The View that has the image just needs a click listener attached to it. When the View with the image is clicked, handle it by either bringing up a new activity with the image as he background (larger version), bring up a Dialog with the image, or add a View from the WindowManager.

Comment: i was thinking about that , but aim searching for other way to popup large image directly without opening all drawled images , so i can't make it direct popup  ?

Comment: Explore all three options I mentioned, each appear as though they are a popup EXCEPT activity (But you can have an Activity show up with the Dialog theme).